# Facebook Registration Plugin works in Sidebar but doesn´t work in page body

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, registration, sidebar

In my site I can have 3 perfectly working versions ([as shown in this image](http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-registration-problem.png)) of the Facebook Registration Plugin (Iframe, XFBML, and HTML5, all taken from developers.facebook.com), the problem is I want the registration form in the body of a registration dedicated page, instead of the sidebar, but if I paste the same exact codes of each version from the sidebar to the content of that dedicated page they won't work, not anyone, you can see by yourself at http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/registro/. (Note the forms in sidebar are text widgets, and for the dedicated page I'm pasting the codes in the page-editor, you know, wp-admin/post.php?post=XXX&action=edit).

It makes no sense to me because the Login Button Plugin works perfectly both in sidebar (at top of it) and in the body of the registration page, as you may see in the same link, above the not-working Registration Plugins.

The codes I'm using are:

Iframe

```
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
               client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&
               redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmanuelmedina.com.mx%2Fgracias%2F&
               fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
          scrolling="auto"
          frameborder="no"
          style="border:none"
          allowTransparency="true"
          width="100%"
          height="330">
  </iframe>
```

XFBML

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#appId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&xfbml=1">
    </script>

  <fb:registration
    fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email"
    redirect-uri="http://manuelmedina.com.mx/gracias/"
    width="530">
  </fb:registration>
```

HTML5

```
  <div
    class="fb-registration"
    data-fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'desired_content','description':'¿Qué tipo de artículos te gustaría ver en esta página?', 'type':'text'}]"
    data-redirect-uri="http://manuelmedina.com.mx/gracias/"
  </div>
```

I'm not sure of which furter information may be useful for you guys to help, but if someone tells me I'm willing to know.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have broken html code. Be sure that wordpress is not filtering and modifying your html. After you paste the code in the Wordpress editor (be sure you do it in HTML mode), change to visual mode and go back again to html. See what changed

Comment: By 'broken html code' you mean the `<div` without closing `>` right? Even that way, the code works perfectly in the sidebar, as you can see live on my homepage (www.manuelmedina.com.mx).

Comment: I just tried switching to visual mode and then back to html mode, and you're right, wordpress changes some code, but i took the codes right from facebook developers page, what can I do?

Comment: One way is create your own shortcode and put it in the page instead of putting HTML directly in the page. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/